# VBA Fill cell color based on value of another cell

Tags: vba, excel

**Using:** Excel 2010

**Goal:** I am trying to say "If D14 equals A, then fill this range with this RGB; otherwise, if D14 equals B, then fill this range with this RGB". If it matters, this script is in a Private Sub.

**Problem:** I am returning this error: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". The strange thing is that it actually did work and changed the fill color of the range, but it still errors out *after* correctly doing so.

**What I've Tried:** This is the code I've been playing around with so far, but cannot figure out how to resolve

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:I1")
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("D14").Value = "A" Then
        .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 210)
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("D14").Value = "B" Then
        .Interior.Color = RGB(51, 57, 64) 'The debugger says the issue is on this line
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Wouldn't conditional formatting be easier?

Comment: @Comintern You are right, but I am also changing the color of shapes on the same worksheet which has to be done through VBA (to the best of my knowledge), so I'd like to keep it all in the VBA script. For the shapes, the script works just fine. Can't get it right for the range though.

Comment: Your code worked fine when I ran it (Excel 2007).  Got a dark gray and a light blue.  Could there be a typo in the actual code?

Comment: I am curious if it's how you have the parentage written. What if you try `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard") | Select Case .Range("D14").Value | Case is "A" : .Range("A1:I1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 210) ...` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("D14").Value = "A" Then
```

This line you define the range

```
    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 210)
```

this line you do not

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("D14").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 210)
```

Comment: *EDIT* only commenting on syntax